# Не выполняется запрос Oracle методом ADO

Tags: c#, oracle, ado.net

Пробую выполнить запрос на оракловский сервер. Соединение с сервером точно есть.

```
var connectionString = @"select distinct a.tablespace_name, SUM(a.bytes)/1024/1024, SUM(decode(b.maxextend, null, A.BYTES/1024/1024, b.maxextend*8192/1024/1024)), (SUM(a.bytes)/1024/1024 - round(c.Free/1024/1024)), (SUM(decode(b.maxextend, null, A.BYTES/1024/1024, b.maxextend*8192/1024/1024)) - (SUM(a.bytes)/1024/1024 - round(c.Free/1024/1024))), round(100*(SUM(a.bytes)/1024/1024 - round(c.Free/1024/1024))/(SUM(decode(b.maxextend, null, A.BYTES/1024/1024, b.maxextend*8192/1024/1024)))) from dba_data_files a, sys.filext$ b, (SELECT d.tablespace_name , sum(nvl(c.bytes,0)) Free FROM dba_tablespaces d,DBA_FREE_SPACE c where d.tablespace_name = c.tablespace_name(+) group by d.tablespace_name) c where a.file_id = b.file#(+) and a.tablespace_name = c.tablespace_name group by a.tablespace_name, c.Free/1024 order by round(100*(SUM(a.bytes)/1024/1024 - round(c.Free/1024/1024))/(SUM(decode(b.maxextend, null, A.BYTES/1024/1024, b.maxextend*8192/1024/1024)))) desc; ";

OracleCommand cursCmd = new OracleCommand(connectionString, connection);

OracleDataReader reader = cursCmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Получаю исключение- {"ORA-00911: неверный символ"} - на строке

```
OracleDataReader reader = cursCmd.ExecuteReader();
```

При этом если  выполнить запрос на самом сервере (просто копирую содержимое строки connectionString ), то он проходит без ошибок

Что делаю не так?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Что делаю не так?

```
var connectionString = @"select .... desc; ";
```

Лишняя точка с запятой `;`.

И всё-таки рекомендую вместо переиспользования переменной `connectionString` для текста запроса использовать новую переменную, чтобы наименованием не вводить в заблуждение людей, который будут читать ваш код.

Comment: andreycha, Stawros - вы правы, точка с запятой лишняя была. Большое спасибо!    И всё-таки рекомендую вместо переиспользования переменной connectionString для текста запроса использовать новую переменную - не совсем понял Вашу мысль, что значит переиспольования и зачем новая переменная?

Comment: Переиспользование переменной - повторное использование одной переменной для другой цели. Так,  `connectionString ` - это строка подключения. В ней содержаться реквизиты сервера к которому подключается  `OracleConnection `. Вы же используете эту переменную для хранения текста запроса, что вводит в заблуждение. Для текста запроса лучше использовать переменную с наименованием вроде  `queryString` или  `cmdText`.

Comment: да, верно. Переименовал в query ). Ещё раз спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Точку с запятой `;` в конце строки уберите. Оракл не принимает ее в качестве разделителя, когда выполняется один запрос.